# In Material-UI why do they set this variable to itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Having some trouble figuring out why Material-UI would set a variable equal to itself for its Popover.

Below is the snippet of code check the two if blocks before the return.

What is the purpose of setting `t.vertical = t.vertical;` ?

```
getPositions(anchor, target) {
    const a = {...anchor};
    const t = {...target};

    const positions = {
      x: ['left', 'right'].filter((p) => p !== t.horizontal),
      y: ['top', 'bottom'].filter((p) => p !== t.vertical),
    };

    const overlap = {
      x: this.getOverlapMode(a.horizontal, t.horizontal, 'middle'),
      y: this.getOverlapMode(a.vertical, t.vertical, 'center'),
    };

    positions.x.splice(overlap.x === 'auto' ? 0 : 1, 0, 'middle');
    positions.y.splice(overlap.y === 'auto' ? 0 : 1, 0, 'center');

    if (overlap.y !== 'auto') {
      a.vertical = a.vertical === 'top' ? 'bottom' : 'top';
      if (overlap.y === 'inclusive') {
        t.vertical = t.vertical; // HERE
      }
    }

    if (overlap.x !== 'auto') {
      a.horizontal = a.horizontal === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';
      if (overlap.y === 'inclusive') {
        t.horizontal = t.horizontal; // HERE
      }
    }

    return {
      positions: positions,
      anchorPos: a,
    };
  }
```

Comment: if `vertical` is a property with getter/setter logic then the assignment might have side-effects.

Comment: I used `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "foo").get;` to check - doesnt look like a getter/setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a typo.

```
getOverlapMode(anchor, target, median) {
  if ([anchor, target].indexOf(median) >= 0) return 'auto';
  if (anchor === target) return 'inclusive';
  return 'exclusive';
}
```

It looks like an overlap of 'inclusive' means the anchor and target are the same.  My best guess is that the original contributor, [chrismcv](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/commit/938109847e01a2dff605d504ce92bc7972f280cb), meant to do this:

```
if (overlap.y !== 'auto') {
  a.vertical = a.vertical === 'top' ? 'bottom' : 'top';
  if (overlap.y === 'inclusive') {
    t.vertical = a.vertical; // update target to match anchor
  }
}

if (overlap.x !== 'auto') {
  a.horizontal = a.horizontal === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left';
  if (overlap.y === 'inclusive') {
    t.horizontal = a.horizontal; // update target to match anchor
  }
}
```

Anchor was just updated, so if overlap is inclusive, this would keep anchor and target in sync.